# Cosine Similarity in Spark

Tags: r, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, data-science

We have a requirement to do imputation of customer missing demographics based on already existing customers. when a new customer is created and if we have his demographics missing we need to impute them using existing customers by finding nearest equivalent customer by other attributes.

For this we are currently using cosine similarity using R. Below is the function used.

```
csim <- function(a, b){
    return(crossprod(as.numeric(a), as.numeric(b)) /
      sqrt(crossprod(as.numeric(a)) * crossprod(as.numeric(b))))
}
```

We have List of sampled customers of 100K. Every day we get almost 6000 new customers who needs some demographics to be imputed. So for each new customer we calculate cosine distance against List of 100K and impute them using attributes of nearest customers.

The above process involves 100K * 6000 iterations in R and takes long time, even using doParllel package. I would like to do the same in spark.

I can see we have RowMatrix class which has method columnSimilarities().But it doesn't seems to solve my purpose.

I have inputRDD- list of input customers - 6k to 7k Vectors
I have SampleRDD- Sample of customers used to impute - 100K vectors.

For each vector in inputRDD, I need to find nearest vector from Sample RDD.

Please help with suggestions